# How to find if tr element exists in a table

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

How can we find if a table contains any row or not. I tried this but got error:

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

```
if($("#tblNames").tr.length > 0)
{
    alert('row exists');
}
else
{
    alert('row doesn't exist')
}
```

For example following HTML of table doesn't contain any `tr`, how can I check this?

```
<table id="tblNames">

</table>
```

Comment: Use `find()`: `$("#tblNames").find('tr').length` or just put it directly in the selector: `$('#tblNames tr').length`. Either way I'd *strongly* suggest you read the jQuery documentation as this is very easily solved if you'd bother to research the correct syntax: http://api.jquery.com

Comment: good trick to not get this kind of error when you are checking prop of object which can be undefined is to use condition `object && object.prop` as if object is undefined, it will not try to check prop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change it to:

```
if($("#tblNames tr").length > 0)
```

---

You have a jQuery object and you are trying to access `tr` node in it, which is not there. Instead change your jquery selector for `tr` as suggested or use `.find('tr').length`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the selector `$("#tblNames tr")` instead of `$("#tblNames").tr` like following.

```
if($("#tblNames tr").length > 0)
{
    alert('row exists');
}
else
{
    alert('row doesn't exist')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("#tblNames")[0].tr.length > 0)
{
    alert('row exists');
}
else
{
    alert("row doesn't exist");
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="tblNames">

</table>
```